# Why scraping detection only 20 img tags?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen,urlretrieve
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
key = input("Enter the image to be searched \n")
urlpath = "https://www.google.com/search? 
   q="+key+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE9- 
   7LjobfAhXCEHIKHQy6A00Q_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=947#imgrc=_"
page_req = Request(urlpath, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page= urlopen(page_req).read()
soup =BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
images= soup.find_all('img')
print("Total"+str(len(images)))
image_links=[]
for img in images:
    image_links.append(img.get('src'))
image_count=0
for link in image_links:
    urlretrieve(link,'image_'+str(image_count)+'.jpg')
    image_count+=1
```

The above script detects only 20 image tags from a google image page. Why it cannot detect all the image tags in the webpage ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML document at that URL only contains 20 images.

The rest are loaded by using JavaScript to modify the DOM after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set better User-Agent to get more than 100

```
user_agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'
page_req = Request(urlpath, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
```